# How to list connected vertices of a non-connected graph

Tags: java, graph-theory

example - there is an unconnected graph with vertices
 A - B - C - D and E - F - G. (a hyphen means that they are connected). 
The code below is using depth-first traversal, I need to modify it to display all connected vertices. eg:
list0: ABCD
list1: EFG
etc...
I don't understand how to implement this.

```
public class Graph {
    private final int MAX_VERTS = 20;
    private Vertex vertexList[];
    private int matrix[][];
    private int countV;
    private StackX theStack;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    public Graph() {
        vertexList = new Vertex[MAX_VERTS];
        matrix = new int[MAX_VERTS][MAX_VERTS];
        countV = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < MAX_VERTS; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < MAX_VERTS; y++)
                matrix[x][y] = 0;
        theStack = new StackX();
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void addVertex(char label) {
        vertexList[countV++] = new Vertex(label);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void addEdge(int x, int y) {
        matrix[x][y] = 1;
        matrix[y][x] = 1;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void displayVertex(int v) {
        System.out.print(vertexList[v].label);
    }

    public void dfs() {

        vertexList[0].wasVisited = true;
        displayVertex(0);
        theStack.push(0);


        while (!theStack.isEmpty()) {
            int v = getUnvisitedVertex(theStack.peek());
            if (v == -1)
                theStack.pop();
            else
            {
                vertexList[v].wasVisited = true;
                displayVertex(v);
                theStack.push(v);
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < countV; j++)
            vertexList[j].wasVisited = false;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    public int getUnvisitedVertex(int vertex) {
        for (int j = 0; j < countV; j++)
            if (matrix[vertex][j] == 1 && !vertexList[j].wasVisited) {
                return j;
            }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DFS does not need to modified.  It needs to be put inside a loop so that each pass will discover one of the lists of connected nodes that your are looking for

```
LOOP
    Select arbitrary vertex
    DFS, saving each visited vertex in list.
    LOOP over visited vertices
       remove from graph
    LOOP END
    IF all vertices removed
       BREAK out of loop
    Start new list
LOOP END
Output lists
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234426/discussion-between-connor-low-and-ravenspoint).